# Tasksel cannot be installed

Tags: apt, lamp, tasksel

I am trying to install tasksel in order to install LAMP but for some reason it always gives me this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package tasksel
root@TheShop:~# sudo apt-get install tasksel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tasksel
root@TheShop:~#
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get update` help?

Comment: Don't tell me that you're not connected to Internet! ;-)

Comment: Why the root account? Why not just install it as a normal user?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy tasksel`?

Answer (score 5):

first try to `sudo apt-get update`

after that, try to install it from Ubuntu software center

if you still have problem, post it by editing your questions

Answer (score 1):

Did you try aptitude instead of apt-get?

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude show tasksel
```

I always use aptitude, gives a lot of useful information.
See also [this thread on severfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/21105/whats-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude)

Answer (score 1):

I have been through the same problem.

The simple solution that worked for me is to set up *software sources* to download from "Main Server".

One way to get to the "software sources" window is as follows:

- Start Ubuntu *Software Centre*
- Go to the *Edit* menu
- Select *Software Sources*
- Change *download from* to the "Main Server"
- Then write these commands one by one in terminal:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install tasksel
  ```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo aptitude install tasksel`  seems to work in natty

As a tip change `install` to `search` to check if package is available